# Upload artifacts from cloudbees to S3

Tags: build, amazon-s3, cloudbees

On my in-house jenkins server I use the S3 plugin to upload warfiles to a s3 bucket. How can I do this wtih cloudbees ? Any plan to integrate this plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is available on the Pro and Enterprise tiers of DEV@cloud, just not the Free and Base tiers.

Answer (score 1):

If the base account level is perfect for you other than S3 file transfer and you are not yet ready for a significant price increase just to get S3 file copy, you may consider this workaround to get files to your EC2:

It is possible to use scripting to get stuff out of your build environment:
http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Accessing+Jenkins+using+HTTP+Basic+Authentication

For example:
curl -u EMAIL:JENKINS_API_KEY https://your_account_name.ci.cloudbees.com/job/job_name/ws/your_file_name > your_file_name

You can do a fingerprint post build process on your file and then check that fingerprint page for md5 hash.